# What is the association rule learning approach to the logical XOR problem?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

The "exclusive or" function has a long and arduous history in the AI/machine learning communities.  From my understanding of "association rule learning", xor would appear to be a problem for this type of learning.  That is, suppose we have the following data:

```
A    B    C
0    0    0
0    1    1
1    0    1
1    1    0
```

Clearly the rule I would seek from this data is that $A\oplus B = C$.  However, it is my undnerstanding that association rule learning techniques would instead discover the rules $A \Rightarrow C$ and $B \Rightarrow C$ each with 50% confidence.

Is my assessment correct that this is a known issue within association rule learning, and if so, are there standard ways of handling such issues?  I can imagine some workarounds, but I'm not sure they fit within the context of association rule learning.

Comment: For me, the problem with XOR is that you have to look at all relevant variables at once to find any clue what's going on -- this of course greatly complicates discovering such rules in many-dimensional systems.

Comment: I'm not an expert in the association rule learning, but what about this: C = A XOR B = NOT(A OR NOT(B)) OR NOT(NOT(A) OR B). Thus, if you introduce new variables X = NOT(A OR NOT(B)) and Y = NOT(NOT(A) OR B), then you will be able to derive the rule C = X OR Y = A XOR B.

Comment: @Leo Yeah I imagined that what you suggested and similar approaches were possible, but they all seemed quite ad hoc.  As such, I was wondering if there was a more robust, standard approach to the problem.

Comment: While you can apply association rules to this idea (don't forget the rule A->B) I'm not sure that it's exactly meaningful in this context.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation you can try to put ~A and ~B into features, then you can learn these rules:

A AND ~B ⇒ C

~A AND B ⇒ C

The problem is the increasing execution time because the number of features is doubled. In addition, you need to know that there is the XOR problem before learning.

Comment: Knowing the problem you're trying to solve makes anything easy.